# To drag and clone multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 divs. I have to clone 3 of them into a separate div by dragging. How do I do it? I also need to keep the original.

Comment: where is your code ?
or create a fiddle for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5ak6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( ".div" ).draggable({ revert: true });
 $("#container").droppable({
    accept: '.div',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone().css('top','0px'));

    }
 });

 });
```

Comment: .css() is just setting the position of this Element. if i remove css('top','0px'). it will append out of droppable like http://jsfiddle.net/Z5ak6/2/

Comment: k. wait i will try in your fiddle.

Comment: Check. you are included jquery code inside $(document).ready(function(){  });

Comment: fiddle dont have that one.so only i ask u

Comment: You didn't include jquery in your fiddle (menu on the left, first drop down list)